# URL crash by Image1.ImageUrl asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, url

Problem:

I change the Image url:

```
chartPic.ImageUrl = "~/Serieschart_pic.ashx?ID=" 
+ Series_ID.ToString() + "&IntervalFrom=" + txtDateFromf.Text;
```

when  `txtDateFromf.Text == "`" it works. (and I will get this image Url: `...testbox1/monitoring/Serieschart_pic.ashx?ID=5&IntervalFrom=` )

when `txtDateFromf.Text` is a date, (Format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff), the image URL bricks and change to somthing like that:  `...testbox1/~monitoring/monitoring/Serieschart_pic.ashx?ID=5&IntervalFrom=2013-04-15%2012:30:00.000`

this Url not works...! why? The only thing is an other get parameter -.-

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing from what you have said that `Serieschart_pic.ashx` doesn't expect the parameter to be passed in as your doing (i.e. `2013-04-15%2012:30:00.000`) but in a different format. Do you the code to the **ASHX** file to see what it expects?

Comment: Added this as an answer but I meant to add it as a comment. But as it is quite long I will leave it here for now so you can reply with more information.

Comment: hey, thx. I found out, with ./ instead of ~/ it works fine... but thats not a smart solution -.-

Comment: Glad you found the solution to your problem!